# Dynamic UITableViewCell not resizing according to the content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Senario A:
If I set the label content in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the cell correctly get resized.

Senario B: 
If I change the text content in custom action in cell, the cell sized does not get changed.(I do call setNeedsLayout + layoutIfNeeded)

How to fix this?

**EDIT:**

1) I have set, 
`myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 71.0`
`myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

2) I have correctly added auto layout constraints.

Comment: did you set label  line size to 0? also height of the row as UITableViewAutomaticDimension ?

Comment: read the tutorial 1. - https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells 2. -https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: Have you tried `tableView.beginUpdates()` followed by `tableView.endUpdates()` after updating the label content?

Comment: Please post the question more detail.Like when you want to resize the cell?clicking or any actions?A little more detail is needed

Comment: @Thilina , do my answer work out for you?

Comment: @Thiha Aung, no mate

Comment: @Thilina, it's time to share your sample project

Answer (score 9):

I was running into this issue, and my problem was that I was constraining the content to `self` (the `UITableViewCell`) and not to `self.contentView` (the `contentView` OF the cell). Hope this helps someone else who has built their cells all in code!

Comment: Thank you so much, I struggled the whole day before reading your answer

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the cell's custom size was enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After you change the text of the cell, just reload that particular cell or simply call `mainTableView.reloadData()`.

To reload that cell-

```
//indexPath is indexPath of cell you just changed label of
mainTableView.reloadRows(at: indexPath, with: .automatic)
```

Comment: I want to show a different text when the user clicks on the cell. So reloading the table doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Whenever you update a `UITableView` you need to keep track of any changes you make using a model owing to the re-usability of cells. After you change the text, if you scroll the screen your changes will be lost. 
Example: In your `cellForRow` you must have initially set the label to be something, if you change it and scroll again without updating a model, the value will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, in the same cell I had an imageView in the top left corner with a "center vertically in container" constraint, and a "top space container" constraint.

Obviously to satisfy this two constraint the cell must have an height equal to:

(height of the imageView / 2) + (length of the top space container constraint).

This height is not enough to fit the label text, so my label had only 1 line visible.

After I have deleted the imageView top constraint all went to the right place, in my case i wanted the image to be centered, if the image had to stay in the top left corner I had to take off the "center vertically in container" constraint.

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't specifically know what was your action on `UITableViewCell`. So, I assume I do that in `UITableViewCell` selection.

> **The below answer only work on iOS 9 and above**

But, for some reason, it failed to do it in **iOS 8** **until it scroll**. So, I will update the answer for iOS 8.

I have seen you have used `UITableView`'s `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` at your project. So,

> **Please check the following**

1. **Make sure `UITableView`'s `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` include inside `viewDidLoad()`**
2. **Make sure your `UILabel` lines set to 0**

[image]

3. **Make sure there is no constraints about height for your UILabel and let the constraints be like that** :

[image]

If there are other component also included, make sure only bottom and top space constraints included or top space to container margin and bottom space to container margin.

4. **Every time that you want to update the cell, you have to reload tableView no matter what your current situation will be.**

So, don't say anything yet before you try this sample project, `@Rikh` answer still work. May be you are going in wrong direction. Here's the solution. Please do as I said steps by steps and let me know if that didn't work out. You might need to share your sample project which is causing.

[image]

**Sample Demo** - [DynamicCellDemo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xo4z9508yw8q23d/DynamicResizeCellDemo.zip?dl=0)

> **UPDATE for iOS 8** : update the following code for iOS 8 users

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        tblDynamic.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is set the AutoLayout constraints for the label in present in the cell from all the sides that is from Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing. Then add the following UITableViewDelegate method to your class.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500
}
```

This will do the job. As now content in table view cell automatically adjusts the height of the cell.

Comment: I have done it myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 71.0 myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Okay.. that will also do the part for these delegate methods. You just need to setup auto layout constraints for the label as quoted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this if it works:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add the following in your viewDidLoad()

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
}
```